# The final local variable token cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java

I'm getting `The final local variable token cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` compilation error at the `token` inside the `forEach` and `lambda` . All I want to do is assign the only item in the list to `token` variable.

PS: I know for sure that there is only one item in the `list`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StringBuilder token;
        AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponse();
        authResponse.getTokens().forEach(item -> {
            token.append(item.getToken());
        });
    }
```

If I declare `token` as an `Instance variable` there is no problem. But is there any other way to do it?

There are a few posts regarding this but I'd like to understand the resolution for this issue

EDIT : I have updated the question to have `StringBuilder` instead of `String`

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't make sense. Why would you iterate over a collection to set the same variable repeatedly?

Comment: @shmosel: I have a gson response which is deserialized in a POJO which has a `List<AuthTokens>` and in the `AuthToken` class I have `String token` and getters (`getToken()` in my case) and setters for it. But I know for sure that there is only one item in the `List<AuthTokens>`

Comment: `getTokens().stream().findFirst().get()` or just `getTokens().get(0)`. I don't see the need for `forEach`.

Comment: Just do `token = authResponse.getTokens().get(0)`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you pls check? How do I resolve this? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Just instantiate the `StringBuilder`. But it still makes no sense to use `forEach` here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign an instance:

```
StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
```

But why are you reinventing the wheel; use something like:

```
String tokens = new AuthResponse().getTokens().stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```